# Aggregating regardless of the order of columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to aggregate a dataframe by two columns so that the variation of these exists only once. The value column should be aggregated by an aggregation function like `max()` or `sum()`

Data:

```
itemID1  |itemID2  |value
---------|---------|-------
B0001    |B0001    |1
B0002    |B0001    |1
B0001    |B0002    |2
B0002    |B0002    |0
```

The result could be:

```
itemID1   |itemID2   |value
----------|----------|---------
B0001     |B0001     |1
B0001     |B0002     |3          #itemIDs could also be ordered in the other way
B0002     |B0002     |0
```

Up to now I have implemented it in SQL to use it via the library sqldf, but sqldf doesn't support WITH-clauses.

Is there a possibility to aggregate dataframes like that directly in R?

Comment: "directly in R" means without using another language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `dplyr` and `pmin` / `pmax` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(ItemID1_ = pmin(itemID1  ,itemID2),
         ItemID2_ = pmax(itemID1  ,itemID2)) %>%
  group_by(ItemID1_,ItemID2_) %>%
  summarize_at("value",sum) %>%
  ungroup

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   ItemID1_ ItemID2_ value
#      <chr>    <chr> <int>
# 1    B0001    B0001     1
# 2    B0001    B0002     3
# 3    B0002    B0002     0
```

Following @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 's comment you can skip the mutate part and have the same output with:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(itemID1_ = pmin(itemID1, itemID2),
           itemID2_ = pmax(itemID1, itemID2)) %>%
  summarise_at("value", sum) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 8):

In `base R`, but it duplicates the data since I work on a copy keeping the original intact.

```
dat2 <- dat
dat2[1:2] <- apply(dat2[1:2], 1, sort)
aggregate(value ~ itemID1 + itemID2, dat2, sum)
#  itemID1 itemID2 value
#1   B0001   B0001     1
#2   B0001   B0002     3
#3   B0002   B0002     0
```

Now you can `rm(dat2)` in order to tidy up.

**DATA.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(itemID1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("B0001", 
"B0002"), class = "factor"), itemID2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("B0001", "B0002"), class = "factor"), value = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L)), .Names = c("itemID1", "itemID2", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution if you feel like sticking to `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select itemID1, itemID2, sum(value) as value 
          from (select case when itemID1 <= itemID2 then itemID1 else itemID2 end as itemID1,
                       case when itemID1 > itemID2 then itemID1 else itemID2 end as itemID2,
                       value
                from df)
      group by itemID1, itemID2")
```

**Result:**

```
  itemID1 itemID2 value
1   B0001   B0001     1
2   B0001   B0002     3
3   B0002   B0002     0
```

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(itemID1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("B0001", 
"B0002"), class = "factor"), itemID2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("B0001", "B0002"), class = "factor"), value = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 0L)), .Names = c("itemID1", "itemID2", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, .(value = sum(value)), 
   by = .(itemID1 = pmin(itemID1, itemID2), itemID2 = pmax(itemID1, itemID2))]
```

> ```
>    itemID1 itemID2 value
> 1:   B0001   B0001     1
> 2:   B0001   B0002     3
> 3:   B0002   B0002     0
> ```

#### Data

```
DT <- fread("itemID1  |itemID2  |value
B0001    |B0001    |1
B0002    |B0001    |1
B0001    |B0002    |2
B0002    |B0002    |0", sep = "|")
```